# Installation stuck now can't even enter Bios

Tags: system-installation

I was installing ubuntu from DVD on windows8 machine and gace the option to delete windows. It stuck at the stage, where you enter your name etc. and I couldn't press next, so I had to switch off computer. Now when I switch the computer it shows black scrren, can't even enter bios. Can you recommend anything?

Answer (score 0):

try to reset your bios with jumper on motherboard

http://pcsupport.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=pcsupport&cdn=compute&tm=9&f=00&su=p504.6.342.ip_&tt=3&bt=7&bts=7&zu=http%3A//www.computercare.ca/forum/showthread.php%3Ft%3D817

and

http://pcsupport.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=pcsupport&cdn=compute&tm=10&f=00&su=p504.6.342.ip_&tt=3&bt=7&bts=7&zu=http%3A//www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000239.htm

might help you.